# Converting Views into tables using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, view, ssis, data-warehouse

Is it a good idea to convert complex views in "db1" into tables in "db2" using SSIS.

the purpose of converting views to tables is to make the reports faster.

Is there any disadvantages or risks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would do much better to make your view schema-bound and add indexes as appropriate. Doing this will actually cause SQL Server to make a concrete copy of the view on your server.

For more information, search for "SCHEMABINDING" in [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx).

Comment: @Adam: Did you mean to say Indexed Views?

Comment: Is that not what I said by telling him to add indexes? Making the view schema-bound is a prerequisite of an indexed view (and the most likely restriction you'll have to make a correction for), which is why I said that. You don't create an "indexed view", you create a schema-bound view and add indexes :)